Trouble Processing Image with chat-4o-mini for Agent-to-Agent Description Sharing (CrewAI framework)
I'm working on a CrewAi project where I need to process an image using the chat-4o-mini model to generate a detailed description of its visual elements (e.g., style, colors, and other fashion-related details). This description should then be shared with other agents for additional processing.
However, I’m facing issues with the image processing and with reliably sharing the generated description across agents. Specifically, the challenges include:
Obtaining a consistent and detailed description from the image analysis.
Sharing this information effectively with other agents, who need it to trigger subsequent tasks.
Would anybody give me some tips on how to solve this?
This is a snippet of my code ...
Analysis of the image uploaded by the user, if available
image_analysis_text = ""
if uploaded_image is not None:
base64_image = encode_image_to_base64(uploaded_image)
image_analysis_task = Task(
    description="Analyze the image uploaded by the user and extract style details.",
    agent=visual_analysis_agent,
    expected_output="Detailed description of the style, colors, and visual elements of the image.",
    context=[
        {
            "description": "Image encoded in Base64 for visual analysis.",
            "expected_output": "Visual interpretation including style, colors, and fashion elements.",
            "type": "image_url",
            "image_url": f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_image}"
        }
    ]
)

Questions:
Are there recommended practices for improving the reliability of the description extraction from the chat-4o-mini model in visual tasks?
How can I ensure seamless sharing of the description across multiple agents in a system where each agent might have different expectations for the data format and content?
Any advice on optimizing this setup or alternative approaches to achieve smooth agent-to-agent communication would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your insights.
